# Firebase/Firestore profile update not successful

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, firebase-storage

I have a react-native application with firestore database. I want to update the user profile by adding profile picture. On my console, I get update successful, but the user's data is usually not updated in the database. So whenever I refresh, the picture disappears. My code is below:

```
const You = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector(currentUser);
  const { name, department, photoURL } = user;

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null)
  
  
  let openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
    let permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
      return;
    }

    let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();
    
    if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
      return;
    }

    setSelectedImage(pickerResult.uri);
  }

  const uploadProfilePicture = async() => {
    if (selectedImage == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const response = await fetch(selectedImage);
      console.log(response)
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const childPath = `profilePicture/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`

      const task = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref()
        .child(childPath)
        .put(blob);

      const taskProgress = (snapshot) => {
        console.log('Transferred: ', snapshot.bytesTransferred)
      }
      
      const taskCompleted = () => {
        task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log('snap ',snapshot);
            console.log('Done')  
            saveProfilePicture(snapshot)
          })
      }

      const taskError = (snapshot) => {
        console.log('Error: ', snapshot)
      }

      task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted)
      }
    
  }

  const saveProfilePicture = (profilePictureURL) => {
    const userProfile = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    userProfile.updateProfile({
      photoURL: profilePictureURL
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("status: " + 'update success');
      dispatch(login({
        photoURL: profilePictureURL
      }))
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("error: ",error)
    });

  }


  useEffect(() => {
    uploadProfilePicture();

  }, [selectedImage])
  
 
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
     
      
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 5}}>
        <View style={{borderColor: purple, borderRadius: 4}}>
                   
          <Avatar
            rounded
            size="xlarge"
            title={extractInitials(name)}
            source={{ 
              uri: photoURL,
            }}
          />

          <Ionicons
            name={
              Platform.OS === 'ios'
                ? 'ios-camera'
                : 'md-camera'
            }
            color={purple_70}
            size={26}
            style={styles.icon}
            onPress={() =>
              openImagePickerAsync()
            }
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 5 }}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: darkerPurple}}>{name}</Text>
          <Text>Department: {convertToUppercase(department)}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

        {/* TODO: List archived issues here */}
      {/* <View style={{marginVertical: 12}}>
        <Text style={styles.boldText}>
          Archived Issues
        </Text>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: white, paddingVertical: 8}}>
          <Text>List archived issues here</Text>
        </View>
      </View> */}
      
      <View style={{marginVertical: 12}}>
        <Text style={styles.boldText}>
          Help
        </Text>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: white, paddingVertical: 10}}>
          {/* {showBox && <View style={styles.box}></View>} */}
          <View style={styles.helpItem}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="card-account-phone"
              size={18}
              color={purple_80}
              style={{paddingRight: 12}}
            />
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Contact Us")}>
              <Text>Contact us</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.helpItem}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="comment-question"
              size={18}
              color={purple_80}
              style={{paddingRight: 12}}
            />
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Faq")}>
              <Text>Faq</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.helpItem}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="file-document-outline"
              size={18}
              color={purple_80}
              style={{paddingRight: 12}}
            />
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Terms and Conditions")}>
              <Text>Terms &#38; conditions</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.signOut}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="logout"
          size={18}
          color={red}
          style={{paddingRight: 12}}
        />
        <Text 
          style={[styles.boldText, {color: red}]} 
          onPress={onSignOut} 
        >
          Sign Out
        </Text>
      </View>
      
      <View style={styles.signOut}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name="delete"
          size={18}
          color={red}
          style={{paddingRight: 12}}
        />
        <Text 
          style={[styles.boldText, {color: red}]}} 
        >
          Delete account
        </Text>
      </View>
    
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

My redux updates, but firestore data does not. Please, what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Can you pls explain  a little bit more what doesn't work. You say "the firestore" data does not change. You don't use any firestore related code in your question.

Comment: The saveProfilePicture function is meant to update the firestore,

Comment: That code is updating the `auth` profile pictire directly and doesn't change anything in `firestore`. If you would share the path on witch to save the data I could provide you with the code that will change it in firestore to.

Comment: The path I save the data is seen on the uploadProfilePicture function, where I have something like this:
const blob = await response.blob();
      const childPath = `profilePicture/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`

Comment: That is the path in the Firebase Storage. Do you realy want to have the same one in the Firestore database. Usualy we use there for user data the `users` path and as ID the user id.

Comment: Yes. I want to use that path as my imageURL. See the firstore documentation I was following.

const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.updateProfile({
  photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Update successful

}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred

})

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There are some bugs in the code and some misunderstandings here. First is the code.

You call your functions like this

```
uploadProfilePicture();
```

but you expect a `profilePictureURL` here

```js
const saveProfilePicture = (profilePictureURL) => {
```

Also, you only update the `auth` profile picture and nothing in the database.

Here is an example that should work and do what you expect:

```js
const saveProfilePicture = (profilePictureURL) => {
  const userProfile = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  //Here we save the picture to the user auth
  userProfile
    .updateProfile({
      photoURL: profilePictureURL,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("status: " + "update success");
      // Here we save to the firestore database
      db.collection("users") // Change this path to something else if you want
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .set(
          {
            photoURL: profilePictureURL,
          },
          { merge: true }
        )
        .then(() => {
          dispatch(
            login({
              photoURL: profilePictureURL,
            })
          );
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
  // You forgot to add selctedImage here
  uploadProfilePicture(selectedImage);
}, [selectedImage]);
```

You can change the path in the database how you want but make sure your database rules allow you to save there something.

Answer (score 0):

See what I changed on the saveProfilePicture function. Thank you all for your contributions.

```
const saveProfilePicture = (profilePictureURL) => {
    const userProfile = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    return firebase.firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .update({
        photoURL: profilePictureURL
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Update success");
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error));

  }
```